# How to do complicated query SQL in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I use three entities: `user, categories, user_categories, articles, articeles_category`

Each user can be subscribe on some categories, so table `user_categories` will be:

```
user_category
    id user_id category_id
    1  1       1

articles_category
    id article_id  category_id
    1  1           1


articles
    id name
    1  Bla
```

So, I need to select all `articles` where `articeles_category` that correspond to the categories on user subsribed in table `user_categories`.

I tried this:

```
Articles::with("categories")->with("publisher.categories")->where("user_id", 1);

public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\ArticlesCategory", "article_id", "id");
    }

public function publisher()
    {
        return $this->hasOne("App\User", "id", "user_id");
    }
```

I have some ideas.

**At first join tables:**

`user_categories` with `articeles_category` by conditions:

```
user_categories.category_id = articeles_category.id AND user_categories.user_id = 4
```

**Second is:**

Select articles from Articles join with previous query.

```
Third is
```

To make global `where` by `user_id`

Comment: Are you using Eloquent?

Comment: Yes, I use this

Comment: In short, you want to get articles from users through categories?

Comment: Yes, I need to get articles on that user subsribed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your models are linked from users to categories to articles, you can do:

```
$categories = $user->categories()->with('articles')->get();
```

Then group them under the same collection (if you want):

```
$articles = $categories->map(function($category){
    return $category->articles;
});
```

Alternatively, if you do not have the user instance:

```
$user = User::find($user_id)->with('categories.articles').->get();
```

See eager loading: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I need to do this on models relations

Comment: So, if skp on table in relations it shoud be: `Articles("categories")->where_in("category_id", array("categories_id from join article.categories.user_categories"))`

Comment: My answer uses eloquent relations assuming that you've set up categories relation on users and articles relation on categories. You only need to join manually if you don't want to use eloquents' relations.

Comment: So, do you do this first from table `User` after join with Articles? Seem I need to use `Has Many Through`

Comment: You don't need has many through following my answer. You see with('articles')? This works if you have articles() relation in categories model. My answer also assumes that you have $user already. You can easily change it to get user from id as well.

Comment: What is `$user`? May be `User::`?

Comment: It's an instance of User. You can replace with User::find($user_id) if you want.

Comment: I still dont understand, I can not use `$user_id` because articles are not bined to user. It works throught `table articles_categories_category_id = user_categories.category_id`. But I can user `where("user_id")` after `categories()` in you sample

Comment: One question please. This `->with('articles')` shoud be in `User` model?

Comment: I get: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::categories()`

Comment: Where `categories` is: `public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CategoryUser', "id", "user_id");
    }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136609/discussion-between-darama-and-jc-lee).

Comment: Hey talk to you later. Not at the computer

Comment: Edited the answer with alternatives.

Comment: Lets goin to chat

Comment: Can we go to chat?